# Definition of Directional Derivative at $P_0(x_0, y_0)$

Tags: derivatives

The derivative of $f$ at $P_0(x_0, y_0)$ in the direction of the unit vector $u = u_1i + u_2j$ is the number

$\frac{df}{ds}_{u,P_0} = \lim\limits_{s \to 0}\frac{f(x_0+su_1, y_0+su_2)-f(x_0,y_0)}{s}$

provided the limit exists.

---

Question is, at above definition, which function does $P_0$ denote?

Comment: I think the notation "$P_0(x_0,y_0)$" is just a confusing way of saying "$P_0$, the point with coordinates $(x_0,y_0)$".

Comment: So I see your a fan of twice ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P_0$ is just the notation for the point $(x_0, y_0)$.